# can you explain how it get this? this is from fourier series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm studying fourier series and I stumble in this equation. and I confuse can tell or explanation how to get that answer:

$a_n= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^2 x \cos(\frac{n\pi x}{2})dx =\frac{1}{2}(\frac{2}{n \pi})^2(\cos(n \pi) - 1)=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{2}{n \pi})^2((-1)^n-1)$

and this

$b_n = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^2 x\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{2})dx = \frac{2 \cos(\pi n)}{n \pi}= \frac{2}{n \pi} (-1)^(n+1) $

Comment: What part are you confused about? How the integration by parts works out or how cos turns into (-1)^n . Also, its helpful to say what you are taking fourier series of. It looks like x on [-2,2] but confirmation would be handy.

Comment: I'm confused about $a_n$ in middle part of equation how to get $(cos(n \pi -1)$ if I solved the middle part and the answer is $ \frac{2]{n \pi} x sin(\frac{n \pi x}{2}) $ $+ \frac{4}{n^2 \pi^2}  cos^2(\frac{n \pi x}{2}) $ and then how to get the right hand of equation of $((-1^n -1)$

Comment: It looks like the Fourier series is of the function $f$ defined by
$$\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \begin{cases}0,&-2< x< 0\\ x, &0\le x < 2\end{cases}\\
f(x+4) &= f(x)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @peterwhy Yes, you are right, I saw the bound of integrals way to late :)

Comment: For integers $n$, $$\cos n\pi = \Re (\cos n\pi + i\sin n\pi) = \Re \left[(\cos\pi + i\sin\pi)^n\right] = \Re\left[(-1)^n\right] = (-1)^n$$

Answer (score 1):

We will be integrating by parts.

$\int_0^2 x\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{2})dx = \frac{2}{n \pi} \int_0^2 xd\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{2}) = \frac{2}{n \pi} [(x\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{2})]^2_0 - \frac{2}{n \pi} \int_0^2 \sin(\frac{n\pi x}{2}) dx $

Now $\sin{n \pi} = 0$ so we are left with only the second term. Integrating again:

$-\frac{2}{n \pi} \int_0^2 \sin(\frac{n\pi x}{2}) dx = (\frac{2}{n \pi})^2 [cos(\frac{n\pi x}{2})]^2_0 = (\frac{2}{n \pi})^2 [\cos(n \pi) - 1]$

Now for finishing touches note: if n is even then $n\pi$ is always a multiple of $2\pi$ so the cosinus is 1 there. If n is odd then $n\pi$ is always a $\pi$ off, of a multiple of $2\pi$. Cosinus is -1 there. We can now conclude:

$(\frac{2}{n \pi})^2 [\cos(n \pi) - 1] = (\frac{2}{n \pi})^2 [(-1)^n - 1]$

Similary we obtain the equation for $b_n$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that the integration steps for the case $n=0$, i.e. $a_0$ and $b_0$, are different :)

Comment: how cosine become -1, it's an  even function pls explain why

Comment: Lets look at what $\cos(n \pi)$ can be for different values of n. $n = 1 \rightarrow \cos(\pi) = -1, n = 2 \rightarrow \cos(2 \pi) = 1, n = 3 \rightarrow \cos(3 \pi) = -1, n = 4 \rightarrow \cos(4 \pi) = 1$. See what is going on here? Cosinus is 1 for multiples of 2pi (even n) and is -1 one pi futher on (odd n). $\cos(\frac{n \pi x}{2})$ is even on [-2,2] but that doesn't ensure that the integral of it times some other function is even, or that it is not negative.